# Implementing multiple pipes in self made shell c++

Tags: c++, linux, shell, pipe

I am just putting the code here for the execute procedure
There exists a structure which contains a member `char* command_list[MAXCOMMANDS][MAXARGUMENTS]`

The first position of each row in this member contains the command and the rest of the items in the row are arguments

I have made the execute procedure which on giving the input `ls | wc` gives **

> DUP2 HERE : Bad file descriptor

Structure below

```
struct command
{
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;    

    int num_commands=-1;
    int num_args[MAXCOMMANDS]={0};

    char* command_list[MAXCOMMANDS][MAXARGS];                   //command and their arguments storage
    vector<string> pr_operator;                         //Pipe or redirection operators storage

    bool background_task;
    bool append;

};
```

Execute function below

```
int execute()
{
    pid_t pid,wpid;
    int status; 

    int num_pipes=count_pipes();    

    int pfds[2*num_pipes];

    for(int i=0;i<num_pipes;i++)
    {
        if(pipe(pfds+2*i)<0)
        {
            perror("Cannot Pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0,j=0;i<=s.num_commands;i++,j+=2)
    {
        pid=fork();

        if(pid==0)
        {
            if(i>0)                                  //if not first command
            {
                if(dup2(pfds[j-2],0)<0)
                    {perror("DUP2 HERE");exit(1);}

                close(pfds[j-2]);
                close(pfds[j-1]);   
            }

            if(i<s.num_commands)         // if not last command
            {
                if(dup2(pfds[j+1],1)<0)
                    {perror("DUP2");exit(1);}
                close(pfds[j+1]);
                close(pfds[j]);
            }


            if(execvp(s.command_list[i][0],s.command_list[i])==-1)
            {
                perror("My Shell");
                exit(1);
            }

        }
        else if(pid<0)
        {
            perror("My Shell");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {   
            for(int k=0;k<2*num_pipes;k++)
                close(pfds[k]);

            for(int k=0;k<num_pipes+1;k++)
                wait(&status);

        }

    }

    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Ugh, make `pfds` a 2-dimensional array, not one long array.

Comment: Have you tried running it with a debugger so you can examine the value of `pfds[j-2]` when the error happens?

Comment: debugger will not help in system calls

Comment: `strace` will help with system calls. Also, `i<=s.num_commands` condition is suspicious.

Comment: s.num_commands is initialized to -1 so when it is 0 then number of commands are 1

Comment: I assure you I have already implemented a function executing single pipes and it(s.num_commands) works perfectly over there